# Reduce level of detail for vector contour lines

Tags: shapefile, simplify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplify Raster Contours ArcGIS 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16842/simplify-raster-contours-arcgis-10)

I have quite a huge shapefile storing vector contour lines: 1GB. I want to create a detailed heightmap for further 3D usage but the level of detail is so high that it crashes all generators. I tried to use:

- ArcGis Desktop 10.1 - TopoToRaster (calculated 7 hours and still not finished)
- Grass - r.surf.contour (created only low quality when converting vector map to raster map)
- Quantum Gis 1.8.0 - Vector->Interpolate->Interpolate (crashed with a bad allocation exception)

I came to the result: I need to simplify my contour lines. Is there a way how I can reduce the level of detail of my contour lines? Basically the process should remove or merge lines to reduce the density.

http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2809/simplified.gif 
(quick version made by hand)

It's okay if the algorithm also simplifies the vectors like MapSharper.

Comment: Methods I used: 
Grass - http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM#r.surf.contour
Quantum Gis - http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/51-inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation-using-qgis.html

Comment: Is it not possible for you to select lines with a certain equidistance (i.e. those for every 5 or 10 meters if you now have for every meter) and export to another shapefile? Or would that lose too much detail in the process?

Comment: Yes I would loose too much detail. In the northern regions there are no mountains and in the south are some. If I just take the contours at a defined interval I would loose the details in the flat regions. The problem is the density of the contours if the heights change.

Comment: A low-tech and a bit crude solution could be to split the contour lines by location for the part with mountains and remove some of them, and afterwards merging the files together again. Although in my experience, Topo to Raster is rather slow to execute, so this may not actually solve the execution time issue. I used it with point data and it took me about 8 hours for some 4-5 million points (with a slow computer, I might add).